# How to make table row appear when the flag is yes only?

Tags: php, html, database

the data wont show up, and i am not sure if my if elase statement is correct a not  .

```
<?php 
require_once ('database.php'); 




$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE flag");


if ((mysql_num_rows($result) == 'yes'){

echo "<table border='1' align='center' >
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>Name</b></td>
 <td align=center><b>price</b></td>
<td align=center><b>day</b></td>
 <td align=center><b>slot</b></td></td>";

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";


    echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";

 ?>
```

if flag is yes display the row of data, if flag is no do not display the row of data

Comment: guessing "flag" is from courselist? ... ``` if ($data['flag'] == "yes") { ```?

Comment: `if ((mysql_num_rows($result) == 'yes')` will never execute. Some int is never going to equal a string. That line will need to be `if ((mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`. Also, you are missing a closing `}`, probably from that same if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE flag
```

I believe this returns more than just one column, so I would go for changes like below. Also I've tested Your WHERE statement on my database. It returns nothing even if I do have data in given colum. You got to compare column to some value.

```
SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE <columnName>="yes"
```

Besides

```
mysql_num_rows
```

> mysql_num_rows — Get number of rows in result

So it will not work

```
mysql_query
```

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>   A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external resource.

This will also not work since You are holding resource there not actually fetched data.

You would need to change rest of code to something like for example:

```
require_once ('database.php'); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE flag");

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<table border='1' align='center' >
<tr>
<td align=center> <b>Name</b></td>
<td align=center><b>price</b></td>
<td align=center><b>day</b></td>
<td align=center><b>slot</b></td></td>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
  echo "</table>";
```

You might not need if in that case since if there are no records with 'yes', then these won't be fetched and so $data in while won't have them.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to pick only those records where flag is yes. And After that, you just need to loop through to all records. Check below code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE flag = 'yes' ");


if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table border='1' align='center' >
        <tr>
            <td align=center> <b>Name</b></td>
            <td align=center><b>price</b></td>
            <td align=center><b>day</b></td>
            <td align=center><b>slot</b></td>
        </tr>";

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=center>$data[0]</td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$data[1]</td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$data[2]</td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$data[3]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Hope it helps you. And please take a note that mysql is deprecated. So you should change your database connecting function to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use the mysqli_ function set over the mysql_ function set so that your code will work no matter what version of php maybe used all the way through php 7+

```
    <?php

    $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'username", 'password', 'database' );

    /* now... check the connection */

    if ( mysqli_connect_errno () )
    {

    echo 'The MySQL(i) Connection call failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error ();

    exit ();

    }

    if ( $result = mysqli_query ( $link, 'SELECT * FROM courselist WHERE flag;' ) )
    {
        /* (?), do we have any resulting row set(s) */

        if ( mysqli_num_rows ( $result ) > 0 )
        {
            /* we have (1) or more resulting set(s), so do this */

    echo "<table border='1' align='center' >
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                <b>
                    Name
                </b>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <b>
                    price
                </b>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <b>
                    day
                </b>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                <b>
                    slot
                </b>
            </td>
        </tr>";

            /* now... process each resulting row set */

            while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) )
            {   

    echo "  <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                $data[0]
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                $data[1]
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                $data[2]
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
                $data[3]
            </td>
        </tr>";

            } // end while ( _fetch_assoc () )

    echo "</table>";

    /* now... free the result set */

    mysqli_free_result ( $result );

        } // end if ( _num_rows () )
} // end if ( _query () )

    /* now... close the connection */

    mysqli_close ( $link );

    ?>
```